# Limit for amplify projects per aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I want to dynamically create amplify projects for one aws account. What is the current limit of amplify projects?

Comment: Check the `Service Quotas` service and see that there is an **adjustable** "Apps" limit of 25 and a non-adjustable "Maximum app creations per hour" of 25. Upper / hard limits are generally not publicly disclosed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find limits (AWS calls them "Quotas") for pretty much anything on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-service-information.html).

For number of Amplify apps, [it's 25 per account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/amplify.html#service-quotas-amplify) (a "soft" limit that can be increased through an AWS support ticket).